# Multiple autocommands in vim

Tags: vim

I've got some sections in my `.vimrc` that look like this:

```
autocmd Filetype ruby setlocal ts=2
autocmd Filetype ruby setlocal sts=2
autocmd Filetype ruby setlocal sw=2
```

now it seems I can convert them to this:

```
autocmd Filetype ruby setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2
```

but here's my question: is there a vim way to have a structure like this?

```
<something mentioning Filetype ruby>
  setlocal ts=2
  setlocal sts=2
  ...
<end>
```

ie, can the `autocmd Filetype` bit somehow be made to address a group of actions? (this is a simple example, I'm really asking for more complicated situations.)

Comment: (completely off topic but in my vim obsessiveness I just realized you can navigate different stack overflow answers with j and k)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can call a function, if you like:

```
autocmd Filetype ruby call SetRubyOptions()
function SetRubyOptions()
    setlocal ts=2
    ...
endfunction
```

Comment: hmmm, this is pretty good - thanks - but any way to tighten it up a little more (ie, remove the need to name and refer to the function)?

Comment: As nice as it would be, vim script doesn't have lambdas :P

Comment: @Peter - Nope. This is as tight as it can get.

Comment: Cominatcha from the future: Vim 8.0 has lambdas.

Answer (score 80):

You can chain most commands with `|`:

```
au Filetype ruby
            \ setlocal ts=2  |
            \ setlocal sts=2 |
            \ ...
```

Not sure if this syntax is better or worse than writing a function.  Some commands can't be chained like this, but you can use `execute` to get around that; see `:h :bar`.

Also see `:h line-continuation` for an explanation of the weird syntax with the `\` at the beginning of the lines.

Answer (score 24):

ftplugins are the neat answer to your question.

1. Ensure your `.vimrc` has a line such as `:filetype plugin on`
2. Define a file named `{rtp}/ftplugin/{thefiletype}.vim` or `{rtp}/ftplugin/{thefiletype}/whatever.vim` (see `:h rtp` for more details).
3. Edit this new file and put your VIM commands in there.  It is probably a good idea to use the  `:setlocal` command to ensure filetype-specific settings are only for that file (e.g., don't turn all comments purple across all filetypes).

See examples in vim distribution if you plan to override default settings ; or among the [many ftplugins I wrote](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/#svn/cpp/trunk/ftplugin/c) otherwise), just write down your `:setlocal`, `:*map <buffer>`, etc. definitions.

It represents some more line to type, but at least, it does scale.

Comment: The only bad thing about ftplugins is that your vimrc ends up being split into dozens of files, and it's less convenient to copy around between computers.

Comment: ftplugins can be distributed and shared more easily than a single monolithic .vimrc. When the configuration becomes rich and complex we can't maintain every thing into one file (see my C++ suite -- and I have similar and yet simpler configurations for other languages). BTW, I don't have a dozen of (non standard) ftplugins, but 78. And there is only 9 of them I'm not maintaining. I'm glad to not have their definition in my .vimrc.
Moreover, copying one's configuration between various computers is as simple as a call to find + xarg + tar.

Comment: I have created my own plugin with a `ftplugin` directory containing a <FileType>.vim file for each file type-specific configuration I want and added this plugin as a bundle in my Vundle setup. That way, configurations for certain file types are kept in their own files and I will get these configurations automatically when activating my Vundle setup.