# How can I make VIM behave differently for different filetypes?

Tags: vim

I have some character maps for typing braces that I'd like to behave differently based on the file's extension - I imagine that would be pretty useful ability to have in general.

Any ideas on how to make this happen from my .vimrc or a plugin?

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are basically two ways. Use the filetype plugin, or use filetype or extension autocommands.

The autocommands (placed in your .vimrc/_vimrc) take the form of either

```
autocmd Filetype cpp set textwidth=100
```

or

```
autocmd BufRead *.cpp,*.h,*.c set textwidth=100
```

(Obviously `set textwidth=100` can be replaced with any other command)

The better solution, particularly if you have alot of custom commands for a filetype, is to use the files `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim` for each filetype. Commands in those files will be executed after loading a file of the given type.

Comment: I suggest you use setlocal so the settings are local only to the buffer. (e.g. setlocal textwidth=100) Use <buffer> for mappings to make them local to the buffer. (e.g.  imap <buffer> } }<Esc>=%``a )

Comment: I checked, tw is a buffer local option. Hence I did not patch jkerian's answer, even if as a general rule we must always use setlocal & co in ft-specif config settings. BTW, peter, isn't cinkeys enough in your use cases ?

Comment: @Luc Thank you for questioning my mapping, I have forgotten why I had set the map. I use cindent and it works great, but cindent does not handle the case of wrapping a chunk of code with conditional or loop. The mapping I gave will re-indent the newly wrapped code block upon the inserting of the closing brace. Without the mapping the just wrapped code block will stay at the same indention level. If you can accomplish this effect with just cindent I would greatly appreciate it if you would share your indention settings. (:set ai? cin? cink? cino? si? inde? indk?)

Comment: @Peter. OK I see. Actually I have surrounding (/-der?) mappings (for all brackets-like characters, control statements) that automatically reindent the surrounded code. Everything is actually available here: http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp#Brackets (provided you are working in C-like languages)

Comment: There's also the [surround plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697), which is pretty good imo.

Answer (score 1):

In complement to [jkerian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649003/how-can-i-make-vim-behave-differently-for-different-filetypes/3649021#3649021), here are a few links to other questions related to ftplugins (as script-local variables, mappings, command, settings, abbreviations, etc shall be used when writing ft specific configuration):

- [Multiple autocommands in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413285/multiple-autocommands-in-vim/1414845#1414845)
- [gVim and multiple programming languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404515/gvim-and-multiple-programming-languages/1404570#1404570)