# How to change vim settings distinctively which each language?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I use vim with many different languages (C, C++, Java, shell, etc.). I know vim already has it preset settings for each language, but I want to change the settings for each individual language to my personal perference. I already have a .vimrc file with settings,but I want a few more files to declare more specific settings according to the language I'm using. What are the files suppose to be called? c.vim? java.vim?

Example: In C, I want my comments to be green, while in Java, I want them to be light purple.

ALSO, I hate vim's preset colorschemes. What's a way I can create my own colorscheme?

I hope that is understandable and complete and makes sense.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @PeterLawrey -1 if I could on a comment.

Comment: Saying "-1" without a response is not useful. Perhaps you mean (and I mean) "vim is perfectly good as an IDE for many purposes, and can be extended with plugins for many more, so I haven't used an IDE for development in years. Diffrent strokes.".

Comment: If you dislike the colorschemes Vim ships with, [here are hundreds more](http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/html/index-c.html)

Comment: In your IDE you can set the colour scheme in your settings. I know some people prefer vim or emacs and these are useful if there is no IDE which handles that language well, but for some languages there are IDE designed for that language and you can do things these editor don't support because they are not designed to be tailored for a specific language.

Comment: @Michael Can you turn that comment into an answer? ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey You can set the colorscheme many different ways in your settings, not in GUI settings, but programmatically in vimscript or in .vimrc according to filetype, etc...

Comment: @Michael +1 your answer.  My comment was a general comment on whether its a good idea to use an editor (no matter how programmable it is) when there are IDEs designed to improve productivity.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, read the question again: the asker is not asking for our opinion on his choice of tools nor is he facing limitations of his editor. He is asking for a better way to organize his language-specific settings and where to find more colorschemes.

Comment: @romainl And the *answer* is to change the colour scheme as Michael, suggests. My *comment* is that if he wants to do much more than change the colours, an IDE is designed to be more productive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use either autocmds:

```
autocmd FileType java colorscheme desert
```

or put the commands in `~/.vim/ftplugin/java_mycolors.vim`. (This is for new settings; if you want to override stuff from the default, system-wide ftplugins, you'd put them in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/java.vim`.)

As you can see, the first approach is quick and dirty, while the latter allows for modularity and lots of customization. Your call.

---

As for changing the colorscheme, this is a global setting; you cannot mix them *at the same time*; but you will only notice that when you split windows or use tab pages, though, so it may be fine.

You can however change the individual syntax colors. By default, comments in all languages are linked to the `Comment` highlight group. Read the syntax file (e.g. `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/java.vim`) or use the SyntaxAttr.vim plugin to determine the group name. Then you can redefine it in your `.vimrc`:

```
:highlight javaLineComment guifg=Purple
:highlight javaComment guifg=Purple
```

This is tedious (depending on how much you want to customize), but more precise, and works in parallel. I'd recommend this unless you really want totally different coloring for each filetype.

Answer (score 9):

You should put all your language-specific settings in the `ftplugin` directory:

```
~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim
```

Answer (score 5):

You want `autocmd`

```
:help autocmd

autocmd FileType c,java map something somethingelse
" Colorscheme just for PHP
autocmd FileType php colorscheme desert
```

By testing the `FileType`, you can specify additional specific settings.  Or, inside your `~/.vim/ftplugin/`, create files for individual types:

```
~/.vim/ftplugin/java.vim
~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim
```

Answer (score 3):

Romainl gave you the [right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12055364/15934), ftplugins are the way to go, but it is incomplete.

As your question is a recurring one, here are a few more complete other answers that I've found:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1414845/15934
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8826323/15934
- [gVim and multiple programming languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404515/gvim-and-multiple-programming-languages/1404570#1404570)