# VIM: Whats the best way for using different languages and plugins?

Tags: vim

iam using vim for programming c++, python and ASM. For each Language i have different specific Plugins, keymaps and so on.

Whats the best way to handle this? Different vimrc's ? Or all in one vimrc and add sth. like if/else depening by the file iam editing?

would be happy about your suggestions and experience

best regards

Comment: for example, you could use local mapping, also autocmd, only if the ft matched, create those mapping.

Comment: I put my `ft` dependent settings in `.vim/ftplugin/<name_of_the_filetype>.vim` files. Like Kent suggests i  define only local mappings in there (see `:h <buffer>`), do some `setlocal` stuff and may define some useful functions. If i want to have some project specific settings i count on the `localvimrc` script. I'm sure that this topic was previously discussed at SO already, but i didn't find it right now...

Comment: ftplugins are the way to go -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055105/how-to-change-vim-settings-distinctively-which-each-language/12055915#12055915

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two approaches: autocommands and ftplugins.

- **autocommands**

  In your `~/.vimrc`, you can add lines similar to this one:

  ```
  autocmd FileType python setlocal tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
  ```

  See `:help autocmd` for more info and examples.
- **ftplugins**

  Put your settings and mappings in this file:

  ```
  ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim
  ```

  See `:help filetype` and `:help ftplugin` for more info and examples.

One thing to consider is the scope of your options and mappings. Some things are global, like `:colorscheme` while some others can be local to a buffer or window like `'tabstop'`, above. Since you want filetype-specific settings it's safer to be as local as possible.

- To make an option local, you must use `setlocal` (note that it won't work with every option, check the `:help` for each one). See `:help :setlocal`.

  ```
  setlocal autoindent
  ```
- To make mappings local to a buffer, use `<buffer>`, see `:help <buffer>`.

  ```
  map <buffer> <F6> ddP
  ```