# How to insert Tabs(not spaces) in vim?

Tags: vim, indentation, vi

I want to use tabs(not spaces) in vim for both indentation and when I specifically press `<Tab>`. I changed my `.vimrc` after looking up on the internet but doesn't seem to work.

.vimrc

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py,*.pyw,*.c,*.h,*.pyx match BadWhitespace /\s\+$/
    \ set tabstop=4
    \ set shiftwidth=4
    \ set softtabstop=4
    \ set textwidth=79
    \ set noexpandtab
    \ set autoindent
    \ set fileformat=unix

set encoding=utf-8
```

Tabs are inserted when i use `<C-v><Tab>` but otherwise spaces are inserted instead of tabs.

Comment: Use [`set expandtab`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces)

Comment: @Fabricator but setexpandtab is used for inserting spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: sorry, i got it the other way around. maybe your syntax is wrong. check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/1413473/3678068

Comment: Upvoted for including this little gem, thanks!  "Tabs are inserted when i use `<C-v><Tab>`". Your question answered mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `<bar>` (`|`) between each command, and you can join the `set`s together:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py,*.pyw,*.c,*.h,*.pyx match BadWhitespace /\s\+$/ |
    \ setlocal tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 noexpandtab autoindent
    \ textwidth=79 fileformat=unix

set encoding=utf-8
```

You can show trailing whitespaces with the listchars `trail`:

```
set listchars+=trail:-
```

Comment: And `setlocal` instead of `set`.

Comment: @romainl Point taken.